# Subspaces of tensor products of Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $A,B,C,D\subset H$ be closed subspaces that intersect trivially. Consider the subspaces $A\otimes B$, $C\otimes D$, viewed as closed subspaces of the Hilbert space $H\otimes H$. (Note that these are all Hilbert space tensor products, i.e. the closure of the algebraic tensor product with respect to the usual inner product on $H\otimes H$). Is it true that $A\otimes B$ and $C\otimes D$ once again intersect trivially?

This seems to be true in the case where all the spaces are finite dimensional, since then the Hilbert tensor product agrees with the algebraic one. However I have had trouble showing that the trivial intersection is maintained upon taking the closure of the algebraic tensor products in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, it turns out this is rather simple. The space $H\otimes H$ can be identified with the Hilbert Schmidt operators from $H$ to $H$ under the identification $(x\otimes y)(z)=\langle x,z\rangle y$. It is then easy to see that under this identification, any element of $A\otimes B$ maps into the space $B$, whereas any element in $C\otimes D$ maps into the space $D$, so they must intersect trivially. (In fact, the assumption that A,C intersect trivially is not needed).